# Is PID considered Steering Behavior?

Tags: movement, ai, steering-behaviors

So I've recently used a PID controller to build a bot for a 2d physics based game. I also did a bit of reading on steering behavior but am still confused over one thing: Is a PID controller considered an implementation of steering behavior? Or are they two completely unrelated things?

Comment: My cursory read of wikipedia tells me that they're *related* but I can't answer the other question. I think so?

Answer (score 1):

I've use the term "steering" to describe PID control.

I find that I often have two parts to control a physics object:

First, a higher level function uses strategy/logic to determine where to steer to.

Next, the lower level function of actually steering towards this point, for which I tend to use PID controllers.

Oh, and as last step, you take the PID output of course, and use it as a force to apply to your physics object. Either as a linear force, or a torque. (If you want to cheat, you could use it to set a velocity, but that makes your simulation discontinuous.)

So to conclude, I think you can say that PID control is a form of steering, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I've implemented a PID controller that is able to navigate a bot to various locations in a game, does that mean that I've implemented steering behavior for the bot? Or is that not the correct terminology?

Comment: Yes, being able to navigate to a desired location can be described as "steering."

Comment: Ok cool. Yeah my PID controller doesn't work too well for following a path because it always tries to stop at each point along the path. I just made it so once it reaches a certain distance from each point (except the last) it should make its target the next point.

Comment: So Bram. Is PID a form of "Steering" or "Steering behavior"? Im confused.

Comment: PID Control is a tool that can be used to implement the steering. Steering is what enables something to move and navigate.

Comment: Ok. So it doesnt have anything to do with "Steering Behavior", only "Steering"?